# Tailwind manually positioning of child div inside grid

Tags: css, reactjs

How can I position manually the child divs inside a grid to the left or right side?

I am using tailwind.

Currently it looks like this:

```
|--------|
|[1] [2] |
|[3]     |
|--------|
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
    |--------|
    |[1] [3] |
    |[2]     |
    |--------|
```

Comment: Look into [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Grid Template Columns which is of class `grid-cols-2` use Grid Template Rows `grid-rows-2`

Refer Doc: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-rows